# PHP Count number of Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, count

Simple question that I am struggling to find answer for.  I have an array as follows:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( [0] => 2014-05-14 02:11:16 [1] => 1 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [0] => 2014-05-19 05:05:17 [1] => 76 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [0] => 2014-05-20 00:28:41 [1] => 35 ) 
    [3] => Array ( [0] => 2014-05-21 01:24:01 [1] => 25 )
)
```

All I need to do is `count` how many Arrays there are.

The answer based on the above would be `4` (0,1,2&3).

I am positive this is a very simple thing but I cannot fathom how - any and all suggestions welcomed.

Comment: And doesn't [count()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) help? It does have a recursive option

Comment: there's 5 arrays. or do you just want to count how many there are at one particular branch of the tree?

Comment: count() on the original array should return 4 in this case.

Comment: @MarcB I dont't see 6 arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [**count()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) should work for you :

```
$num = count($array);
```